# How to call vue list data property in an if statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created an array grid using canvas, and I am trying to set each square with a specific state. I want the fillstyle to be determined by the state, however I am unable to call the data inside the state property. I have tried using this. and I have tried to call it above in the data function however none seem to work

```js
data: () => ({
width: 1200,
height: 800,
squareH: 15,
squareW: 15,
squareRow: 40,
squareCol: 40,
squares: [],
ctx: null,
node: 'e',


 }),
methods: {
    initGrid() {
      
      let grid = document.getElementById('grid');
      this.ctx = grid.getContext('2d');
      for (let c = 0; c < this.squareCol; c++){
        this.squares[c] = [];
        for(let r = 0; r < this.squareRow; r++){
        
          this.squares[c][r] = {x: c* (this.squareW + 3), y: r* (this.squareH + 3), state: 'e'};
        }
      }
      if (this.squares.state == 'e'){
            this.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
          }
    else if (this.squares.state == 's'){
            this.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
          }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are populating the Squares, you are only ever setting the state = "e", so are you only seeing the white and black squares? no red?

```
this.squares[c][r] = {x: c* (this.squareW + 3), y: r* (this.squareH + 3), state: 'e'};
```

try something like this

```
this.squares[c][r] = {x: c* (this.squareW + 3), y: r* (this.squareH + 3), state: (r+c)%2=0? 'e':'s'};
```

not sure if you can set the state in the object with a ternary, but if not, move it to a method

The (r+c)%2 will alternate across the rows, checkerboard style, I believe